# Migrating from source

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I want to migrate data from an old Elastic Search deployment to a new one with a newer version. [I read that the only way to do so is by 'migrating from source'.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-data.html)

I can't really find any documentation on this. Do they really just mean uploading all the data again from the same source that you aquired it from before?

Answer (score -1):

Reindexing from source data is not the only option, however, I would say it’s probably the best one in terms of quality and easiness

Other options are:

- [Reindex from remote](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote). The caveat here is - that your `_source` on the original cluster should be enabled, otherwise it wouldn’t be possible, since reindexing is basically taking the `_source` content and indexing it once again
- [Restoring snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) made on the old cluster. Snapshots are effectively copy of Elastic files, so, unfortunately there are limitations: snapshots of indices created in **1.x** cannot be restored to **5.x** or **6.x**, and snapshots of indices created in **2.x** cannot be restored to **6.x**.  But, even if you’re in the situation like this - you still should be able to migrate snapshots via intermediate suitable Elastic version

Comment: But the documentation tells me that for those 2 options, my version should be the same https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-data.html

Comment: @Titulum I'm not 100% sure what this elastic service is, but it's definitely possible for normal Elasticsearch cluster

Comment: This topic is about elastic cloud deployments, not local clusters. Does this still apply?

Comment: @Titulum I don't see why it shouldn't apply to the cloud deployment as well